# gulp-cssmin TypeError cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to minify my code .
but t have this issue

```
D:\gulp-compiler\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\clean-css\lib\selectors\extractor.js:66
  return name.replace(/^\-\w+\-/, '').match(/([a-zA-Z]+)/)[0].toLowerCase();
                                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at findNameRoot (D:\gulp-compiler\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\clean-css\lib\selectors\extractor.js:66:59)
    at extract (D:\gulp-compiler\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\clean-css\lib\selectors\extractor.js:36:9)
    at restructure (D:\gulp-compiler\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\clean-css\lib\selectors\restructure.js:297:22)
    at optimize (D:\gulp-compiler\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\clean-css\lib\selectors\advanced.js:71:5)
    at minify (D:\gulp-compiler\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\clean-css\lib\clean.js:228:5)
    at whenSourceMapReady (D:\gulp-compiler\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\clean-css\lib\clean.js:135:7)
    at Object.whenDone (D:\gulp-compiler\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\clean-css\lib\clean.js:155:14)
    at processNext (D:\gulp-compiler\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\clean-css\lib\imports\inliner.js:105:13)
    at importFrom (D:\gulp-compiler\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\clean-css\lib\imports\inliner.js:79:10)
    at processNext (D:\gulp-compiler\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\clean-css\lib\imports\inliner.js:104:16)
```

i try search for my issue but no new 
my gulp js is 
// copy css and minify from development to deployment

```
gulp.task("compress-css", () => {
  return gulp.src( pathGo+"css/**/*.css")
   .pipe(cssmin().on('error',function(e){
        console.log(e)
  })) 
  .pipe(gulp.dest('testing_folder/css1'));;
});
```

notice i used proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the issue that css file is't writing correctly ( Files ready from framework ,the framework can work with this files   ).
i try move my files away  from  framework css files and run gulp 
so gulp is running  and minify  correctly
thanks for all
I wish my answer help you if  the same issue faced you

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, the final discovery is that I quote the font file syntax error.

before

```
@import url(../font/PingFangSC.ttf);
```

after

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'PingFang SC';
src: url('../font/PingFangSC.ttf');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
```

why CSS not provide syntax for compilation checks？